# How do I avoid printing certain data that contains "None" as a value?

Tags: python

In my code below, the times variable prints data in calendar and business time. Some of the data have numbers and others print the value 'None'. I would like to only print data that does not have the value 'None'. When I run my code I still get all of the data printed.

```
for ticket1 in ticket_list1:
    for ticket2 in ticket_list2:
        times = ticket2['reply_time_in_minutes']
        ticket_id = ticket2['ticket_id']
        assignee = ticket1['assignee_id']
        priority = ticket1['priority']
        if ticket1['assignee_id'] != ticket1['requester_id']:
            if times['calendar'] != 'None':
                print("%s %20s %20s %20s" % (times, ticket_id, 
assignee, priority))
```

Comment: `None` is a type in python, `"None"` is a string containing the word "None". If you want to filter out the type `None` you just need to remove the quotes.

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around none. `None` is actually a value - of `<type 'NoneType'>`. So it cannot be compared to a string.

```
if times['calendar'] != None:
```